# Cordova don't deploy to my android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, cordova

I builded my app with cordova and just try to run it on my emulator but it seems to load forever[image]

i don't understand why the app is not deployed even if my emulator is running

This the command that i executed:

```
npx cordova build android
npx cordova prepare android
npx cordova run android
```

Comment: How are you actually trying to start the application? What command are you executing?

Comment: i edited the post :) ty for help

Answer (score 0):

To run a Cordova build application on an Android emulator you need to use an additional command line switch.

So change

```
npx cordova run android
```

to

```
npx cordova run android --emulator
```

If this doesn't work, you can try to execute the following command

```
cordova run android --list
```

to get a list of detected connected devices and ultimately try to target your desired device using:

```
cordova run android --target=one of the available devices
```

Comment: Ty for Answer ! I just tried your solution and it produce the exact same result :( Cordova is searching for an emulator by default if no device are plugged

Comment: What do you get if you try to list connected devices using `adb devices`?

Comment: i see my emulator in the list